# React Final Form re-renders all fields while changing one of them

Tags: react-final-form, final-form

It is written in docs, that

> The `<Field/>` will rerender any time the field state it is subscribed to changes.

So, if I'd have several Fields, all of them will be re-rendered, while changing only one of them.
Are there any ways to prevent re-renders of other Fields, that are not changing at the moment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's because your entire form is rerendering. Your question is exactly the reason that Final Form was designed from the ground up to allow fine grained render control.

[Here's a video](https://youtu.be/v1JAUiqskiw?t=818) of me explaining it last month.

Check out [this example](https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/examples/subscriptions) of how to do it.

Answer (score 5):

Another workaround is to use `React.memo` (react version >= 16.6.0)

Make each input field a separate component an wrap it in memo.

```
export default React.memo(MyInputComponent);
```

If you are passing values down to `MyInputComponent`, pass only the needed prop value **not the whole form data object**.

```
<MyInputComponent value={formData.myValue} />
```

This way the `MyInputComponent` will re render only if `formData.myValue` has changed.